# YouTube app comments

Tags: youtube

I've got the YouTube Android app. Several videos endwith the youtuber asking to leave comments below. Where is this? All I see is an expand arrow, a like button, a dislike button, a share button, and a subscribe button. Thanks.

Comment: Scroll down, below the suggested videos are the comments.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was an infinite list. Is there also a way to send a private comment rather than a public comment? P.S. You may want to make your post an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: comments section, has been made a pop-up instead of a permanent part of the UI, now has an icon alongside the 'like' and 'dislike' functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll down to find the comment field. Your comment will be public.